# @Ajax.ActionLink post form fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I have the following form where I am adding items to a list and updating the resulting table. so here is the code I currently have:

**View (strongly typed):**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddService", "Manager", 
           new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "servicePartial", 
                             HttpMethod = "Post", 
                             LoadingElementId = "loading" }))
{
       <input type="submit" value="Add New" />                
       <div class="widget-content table-container" id="servicePartial">
            @Html.Partial("_Services", Model)
       </div>
}
```

**Partial:**

```
@model Project.Model.ServicesViewModel
<table id="demo-dtable-02" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <td class="action-col">Actions</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="services">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        if (Model.Services != null)
        {
            if (Model.Services.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Services.Count; i++)
                {
                     <tr>
            <th>@Model.Services[i].name</th>
            <th>@Model.Services[i].price</th>
            <td class="action-col">
                 @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Services[i].name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Services[i].price)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Services[i].serviceId)
                @Ajax.ActionLink(" X ", "Appointment", "Manager", 
                                 new{ model = Model, 
                                      id = @Model.Services[i].serviceId }, 
                                      new AjaxOptions
                                       { 
                                           UpdateTargetId = "servicePartial", 
                                           LoadingElementId = "loading",
                                           HttpMethod="Post" 
                                       })
            </td>

        </tr>
                }                   
            }
        }

    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ServicesViewModel
{
    public List<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, the post back through the submit button of the `Ajax.Beginform` works and I'm able to post back the model and update the services (add one to it) and return it.

My problem is that I would like to be able to delete a service from the list too. for this I thought I would use a `Ajax.Actionlink` and it does post back with the id. the problem is that it only returns the id and not the model.

Now looking around its Apparently not possible to send the current model back to the action using the `Ajax.Actionlink` how would you guys handle this?

I thought I would be clever and use an overload of the `Ajax.Actionlink` and add 
  `new{ model = Model, id = @Model.Services[i].serviceId }` to it but its a no go.

There are a lot of other data in the ViewModel (for space I've taken it out of the above code) and its very impractical for me to send all these data one by one through the above overload.

Comment: How are you going to delete the item? Can you plz post the action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use form.serialize method to post the entire form to the action using ajax call. Instead of using an action link, try a button. And in the onclick event of that button, serialize the form and submit it.

```
$('#deleteButton').click(function(){

    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url:'@Url.Action("deleteActionName")',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    } );
  } );
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help on this. This solution won't however work by itself since I need to also send back the id of the row (that the button is on) so that the action will use to delete the service from the ViewModel. The Delete button is sitting on each row of the table and I do have access to the serviceId. Thanks again

Comment: In that case you could save the id in a hidden field and submit it along with the form.